# json Deserializer in to target object

Tags: java, json

Can you recommend on a Json Deserializer that can deserialize into existing object (**merge 2 objects**)?
When the user submit a form I want to save that into the db this way:

this is the json from the client:

```
{"affiliateId":1,"name":"First Affiliate","email":"email@gmail.com","user.userName":"test","user.password":"pass-hashed","employee.employeeId":1}


Affiliate affiliateFromDb = affiliateApi.getFromDbById(1);

SomeDeserialization json = new SomeDeserialization();
affiliateFromDb = json.fromJson(affiliateFromJson  , affiliateFromDb );//affiliateFromDb = target bean
```

Meaning that I want the affiliateFromJson to be interpolated into  affiliateFromDb.
And than I will call

```
 affiliateApi.save(affiliateFromDb);
```

Note that the json contains deep deserialize, user.userName

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)! In particular, see the [Object Examples](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Object-Examples).

```
class BagOfPrimitives {
  private int value1 = 1;
  private String value2 = "abc";
  private transient int value3 = 3;
  BagOfPrimitives() {
    // no-args constructor
  }
}

BagOfPrimitives obj2 = gson.fromJson(json, BagOfPrimitives.class);
```

The only catch here — but you **will** have this same problem with any other JSON (de)serializer — is the nonstandard "deep" object format you want to work with. You would have to use something like this instead:

```
{"affiliateId":1,"name":"First Affiliate","email":"email@gmail.com","user": {"userName":"test","password":"pass-hashed"},"employee.employeeId":1}
```

Comment: Thanks, but where is the merge here? I want to merge the object with an existing object. see my code again mayby, Thanks

Comment: I don't think you're going to find a JSON library that does this for you. Write a custom method on the `Affiliate` object, something like `Affiliate#mergeWith(Affiliate other)`.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(responseString);
```

Comment: Thanks, but where is the merge here? I want to merge the object with an existing object. see my code again mayby, Thanks